# Calculating minimal discriminator of a set of columns in a matrix with unique rows

Tags: time-complexity, knapsack-problems

Having a matrix $M$, with unique rows, how to calculate a minimal subset of colums $D$ such that every row is unique? Also, how to maximize the amount of unique rows, if the number of chosen columns is limited?

For example:

$M$ =

```
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 2
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 2 0 0
```

$D$ (columns {4, 6} from $M$) =

```
0 1
0 2
1 0
2 0
```

It seemed like a Bounded Knapsack Problem at first, but the weights of each item in knapsack depends on other items, so it's not a classical knapsack problem.

Is there a known solution for this problem?

Comment: Do you want the discriminator to be *minimal* (i.e., no column of the discriminator can be removed while keeping rows unique) or *minimum* (i.e., there is no other discriminator with less columns)? In the former case it is easy to come up with a polynomial-time algorithm that computes a minimal discriminator, simply start with all the columns and iteratively try to remove each of of them. In the latter case the problem is NP-hard. See my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can grasp the idea of a *minimal*. Seems like a greedy algorithm, which does not give the best possible solution, because keeping a certain column might allow for removal of many other columns. I think it could be used as an approximation which is fast to compute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is NP-hard by a straightforward reduction from [the problem of finding a discriminating code in a bipartite graph](https://www.aimsciences.org/journals/displayArticles.jsp?paperID=3786).

Let if $G=(I \cup A, E)$ is the bipartite graph with $I = \{i_1, \dots, i_n\}$ and $A=\{a_1, \dots, a_m\}$, you can create a matrix $M$ with $n$ rows and $n$ columns. The entry on the $j$-th row and $k$-th column is $1$ if $(i_j, a_k) \in E$ and $0$ otherwise.

A minimum discriminator of $M$ induces discriminating code of $G$ having the same size, and vice-versa.